# HTML and CSS click button to view Image

Tags: html, css

Im a beginner of HTML and CSS My problem is I want a button that if you click it. the image will change. for example I have 3 images. "image1.jpg", "image2.jpg" and "image3.jpg" and also 3 buttons name "1", "2" and "3" when I click 1 the image 1 will be view then if I click 2 the image 2 will be view. like Demo 6 in this website http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/. but it has a java script. ONLY HTML and CSS can be used. is that possible to achieve?

```
<div id="cf7" class="shadow">
  <img class='opaque' src="/Picture/image1.jpg" />
<img src="/Picture/image2.jpg;" />
<img src="/Picture/image3.jpg;" />  
</div>
<p id="cf7_controls">
 <span class="selected">Image 1</span>
 <span>Image 2</span>
 <span>Image 3</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to do so with only HTML and CSS, with checkbox hack (ref: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/17/css-click-events/ ).

Basically, you hide the checkbox and use the label to trigger the click event. Then, add  CSS rules like this:

```
input[type=radio] {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
}

label {
    display: block;
    background: #08C;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.imghide{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}

#radioimage1:checked ~ #image1 {
    display:block;
}
```

Fiddle demo : http://jsfiddle.net/lparcerisa/gzvytjzf/1/

Comment: Last question sir. how can I select already the image 1? like no need to click it. when the page will load it is already selected?

Comment: you can force the first image to be `display:block`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/lparcerisa/gzvytjzf/3/

Answer (score 0):

No. Handling events such as a button click is not possible in bare HTML/CSS

Comment: This is not an answer. It should have been a comment.

Comment: The original question was "is this possible?" and the answer is "no its not"

Comment: Actually it kind of is... see `checkbox hack`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! would like to ask if there's any way or alike what I want to achieve using HTML and CSS only?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with base css, and toggle in jquery

You can use Minified.js.

See the possibilities with this framework. The best framework is which I am using, this is responsive and lightweight, you will get all the features of Bootstrap at 12KB (zipped), and it is easy to understand. You will get page speed of 100 on mobiles too.

Check this: http://skhost.in/one

Click to check the speed: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fskhost.in%2Fone&tab=desktop

Comment: OP does not want a JS/JQ solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using the focus and ~ selectors in css to change a background image:

```
#button:focus~#image {
    background-image: url('./your_image.jpg');
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xvLke7gj/

The benefit of this method is that you can control the image with the keyboard.